# Linking two tables in dbContext where one key is not defined in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've spent a bit of time looking at this and cannot find an answer online (Perhaps I am searching for the wrong thing..)

Below is a simplified version of the problem.

I have two tables:

Table 1 : Areas

```
AreaID   |   Group 1  |   Group2  |   Group3
----------------------------------------------
1        |   2        |    22     |     10
2        |   5        |    1      |     9
3        |   4        |    3      |     2
```

Table 2 : Groups

```
GroupID   |   Group   |   Code   |   Description
-------------------------------------------------
1         |   1       |   2      |   Description 1
2         |   1       |   5      |   Description 2
3         |   1       |   4      |   Description 3
4         |   2       |   22     |   Description 4
5         |   2       |   1      |   Description 5
6         |   2       |   3      |   Description 6
7         |   3       |   10     |   Description 7
8         |   3       |   9      |   Description 8
9         |   3       |   2      |   Description 9
```

So the SQL to get the Group description for Area 1 Group 3 would be:

```
Select g.Description from Areas a
    inner join Groups g on g.Code = a.Group3 and g.Group = 3
where a.AreaID = 1
```

To clarify the Areas table has one Foreign Key linking it to the Groups table, but to get a unique record from the groups table you also need to have the "Group" column.
This is fine using ADO.Net or Stored procs, but we really would like to use EF and be able to navigate between the entities properly.

I also need to point out that for the purposes of this project we ONLY need the Group3 from the areas table, we are not interested in any other groupings at the moment.

Where I am upto:
I have created classes to represent the tables in my project, I have added modelbindings to the context to define a relationship between the Area and the Group based on the Area.Group3 column mapping to the Group.Code column and this works (Its essentially a many to many relationship in EF at the moment) but it also brings out all of the rows for other groups where the Code column matches (Such as code 2 in the example above brings back GroupIDs 1 and 9)

What I would like to be able to do is constrain it in the context by saying something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Area>()
.hasRequired(a=>a.Group)
.WithMany(g=>g.Areas)
.map(m=>
{m.MapKey("Group3")});
```

but of course the above without a constraint on Group.Group = 3 brings back multiple groups for each Area which in turn breaks because the binding is telling it to expect one!

Thats a bit of a ramble, if anyone needs clarification on the above to be able to help let me know and Ill get the info to you!

Thanks

Comment: FYI for the time being I have accepted that these relationships dont work -  so whenever I have to drill down from an area to a group I am having to do a separate query - it works but its hardly efficient!